# How can a default-constructed object of a non-copyable class be emplaced into a boost::container::map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, boost, emplace

Consider the folllowing C++03 code (I have to make the code compatible with pre-C++11 compilers):

```
// This class belongs to a third-party SDK and cannot be touched
class A {
public:
    explicit A();
    explicit A(bool b);
private:
    // Non-copyable
    A(const A&);
    const A& operator= (const A&);
}

boost::container::map<int, A> myMap;
```

Using a Boost map here because it allows emplacing even in C++03. The problem is that I can perflectly emplace-construct into the map if using the one-argument constructor, but I don't know how to default-construct the object, as this code illustrates:

```
myMap.emplace(1, true); // Works
myMap.emplace(1);       // Fails
```

The second call fails because it's taken as a call to the emplace(std::pair...) overload so it seems there is no way to "default-emplace".

Is there any way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of interest I played with this

As an important datapoint, I knew that `std::map` (in C++11) supports *piecewise construction* of it's value pairs:

```
std::map<int, A> stdMap;
stdMap.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, 
     std::forward_as_tuple(1), 
     std::forward_as_tuple());
```

would therefore invoke the contructor you're after. However, somehow, the same doesn't immediately work for Boost's `map`. Hmmm.

However, this piqued my interest: boost uses `std::pair<const K, V>` as the value type?!

```
boost::container::map<int, A>::value_type p { 
       std::piecewise_construct, 
       std::forward_as_tuple(1), 
       std::forward_as_tuple(true) 
};
```

works no problem. And I can also verify that this typedef is *in fact* the type stored:

```
static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(p), std::remove_reference<decltype(*myMap.begin())>::type>::value, "Nonstandard pair");
```

So, it's beginning to look like a bug in the forwarding via the interal tree implementation when it uses the `allocator::construct` call.

Comment: But `std::piecewise_construct` is not available on C++03 and I have not found a replacement for it in Boost. Now I believe it can't really be done in m scenario.

Comment: @Doodler I would concur. You could play very dirty tricks doing placement new in the value object. However, it's probably a lot easier to create a strong type around A that allows 'explicit' default construction overload... Of course this being C++03 this would include manually exposing the "inherited" constructors (since neither variadics or inherited ctors can be employed). Not fun.

Comment: After having found [`boost::unordered::piecewise_construct`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/unordered/compliance.html) your answer makes full sense, so I'm marking it now as the right one.

Answer (score 4):

By making `A` moveable, but not copyable, and then moving the object to the emplacement function.

In C++03, you can use [Boost.Move](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/move.html) to make `A` moveable.  Example:

```
#include <boost/container/map.hpp>
#include <boost/move/move.hpp>
#include <cassert>

class A { 
    BOOST_MOVABLE_BUT_NOT_COPYABLE(A)
public:
    explicit A() {}; 
    explicit A(bool b) {}; 
    A(BOOST_RV_REF(A)) {}
    A& operator=(BOOST_RV_REF(A)) { return * this; }

private:
    // Non-copyable
//    A(const A&);
//    const A& operator= (const A&);
};


int main()
{
    boost::container::map<int, A> myMap;
    myMap.emplace(1, true); // Works

    A a;
    myMap.emplace(1, boost::move (a));
//  myMap.emplace(1);       // Fails

}
```

Comment: Thank you, John. Unfortunately, I forgot to mention that the "A" class is not under my control.

Comment: @Doodler:  Oh, my goodness.  Now that does complicate matters somewhat.

Comment: Actually, the solution **should** be simple: `piecewise_construct` was designed for this (among other things). See, however, my answer for the prelimary results.

Comment: At this point I believe John's answer is the most right one because it's at least a solution for the problem as I formulated it formerly (with a touchable A class).

Answer (score 0):

piecewise_construct support was added recently for Boost 1.62. So the following code:

```
#include <boost/container/map.hpp>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>

// This class belongs to a third-party SDK and cannot be touched
class A
{
   public:
   explicit A(){}
   explicit A(bool b);

   private:
   // Non-copyable
   A(const A&);
   const A& operator= (const A&);
};

int main()
{
   using namespace boost::container;
   map<int, A> myMap;

   myMap.emplace(piecewise_construct, boost::tuple<int>(1), boost::tuple<>());

   return 0;
}
```

should work in C++03 and C++11+ compilers.